# Partitioning Strategy For Complete Graph In Spark GraphX

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

I have created a graph using Spark graphX in which every vertex is directly connected to every other vertex of graph i.e **Complete graph**. 
Please if anyone can suggest good partitioning strategy for this type of situation or any ideas to implement custom partition strategy.

**I have 1 million vertices and 500 million edges.**

Any ideas or suggestions related to this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a complete graph, you do not have to care about sophisticated partitioning algorithms. Just take the random partitioning method which is already implemented by GraphX.

If you have n graph vertices and k partitions, any [balanced (edge-cut) partitioning strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) will assign about n/k vertices to each partition which results in (n-n/k) outgoing edges per partition to other partitions: each vertex is connected to each other vertex on each other partition.